# SQL Server Users

Tags: sql-server

Based on these system scalar Functions:

`@@CONNECTIONS`:This function returns the number of attempted connections - both successful and unsuccessful - since SQL Server was last started.

`@@MAX_CONNECTIONS`: Returns the maximum number of simultaneous user connections allowed on an instance of SQL Server. The number returned is not necessarily the number currently configured, returns always 32767.

**My Question is this**: We know millions of users can connect to sql server at the same time why `@@MAX_CONNECTIONS` says that only 32767 users can connect to sql server at the same time.

Comment: Read this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125279/max-number-of-user-connections

Comment: One may have millions of concurrent users but not all are actively executing query simultaneously. Connections are aggregated at the app service layer and also pooled so the actual number of connections is a fraction of the number of users.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft covered this topic describes how to set the user connections server configuration option in SQL Server 2017 by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL.

- The user connections option specifies the maximum number of       simultaneous user connections that are allowed on an instance of SQL     Server. 
  The actual number of user connections allowed also depends    on the    version of SQL Server that you are using, and also the limits    of    your application or applications and hardware.  SQL Server allows a      maximum of 32,767 user connections.  Because user connections is a     dynamic (self-configuring) option, SQL Server adjusts the maximum       number of user connections automatically as needed, up to the maximum    value allowable.

For example, if only 10 users are logged in, 10 user
   connection objects are allocated. In most cases, you do not have to
   change the value for this option. The default is 0, which means that
   the maximum (32,767) user connections are allowed.

[more description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)